# Query to exchange letter position in the word

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I write query for exchanging letter positions of a word in particular column of a table?

**Example:**

```
 HAPPY  -> PHAPY
 TIRED  -> RTIED
```

How can I do this?

Comment: its unclear what are you're asking?

Comment: Do you want the third letter repositioned to the beginning?

Comment: This can be achieved in SQL, but I don't think SQL is the right technology to do this. You can this in your frontend technology, as frontend technologies have Array etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Declare @YourText NVARCHAR(100) = 'HAPPY'

Select Substring(@yourText,3,1)+STUFF(@YourText,3,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **shuffle letters in word**, you can try below query. You can make this as UDF.

```
DECLARE @Word VARCHAR(20) = 'HAPPY'
DECLARE @NewWord VARCHAR(20) = ''
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @Pos INT

WHILE LEN(@Word) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Pos = CAST(RAND()*10 AS INT) % LEN(@Word) + 1
    SET @NewWord = @NewWord + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(@Word, @Pos, 1),'')
    SET @Word = STUFF(@Word, @Pos, 1, '')
    SET @Count = @Count + 1
END

SELECT @NewWord AS NewWord
```